# Pulling out the limit inside another limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In proving the second order derivative formula $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=f''(a)$$for a function $f$ of class $C^2$, we can approach by using the definition of derivative:

\begin{align}f''(x) &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f'(x)-f'(x-h)}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}-\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-t)}{t}}{h} \\&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+t)-2f(x)+f(x-t)}{t}}{h}\end{align}

If we can somehow "take $t=h$", we get the desired formula. But why can we do it?

Comment: In the second equality, in the far right limit, it should be $x-h$ instead of $x$, otherwise you get $f'(x)$ instead of $f'(x-h)$.

Comment: @Alizter: that is not true. See ABC's comment to your answer.

Comment: This result is more general. If $f''(a)$ exists then this formula is valid. However there may be cases when the limit on the left exists but $f''(a)$ does not exist. Proving the formula by just assuming the existence of $f''(a)$ is slightly hard but very instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it using l'Hopital rule:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a-h)}{2h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f(a)+f(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)+f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{2h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}f''(a)+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(a-h)-f'(a)}{-2h}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}f''(a)+\frac{1}{2}f''(a)$$

$$=f''(a)$$

Comment: I think the OP should know different approaches attacking the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about $t=h$. You are getting the "right" formula just because you are mistyping the Newton quotient for $f'(x-t)$.